# Tunneling over SSH to use VNC via gateway

Tags: ssh, vnc, tunnel

Does anyone give me any hint with this situation. I have my desktop-computer (running on Ubuntu) in my company. Company has vpn gateway which helps me to connect my desktop-comuter via ssh. Now I want to remotely control my desktop-computer at home with VNC. I have already installed xtightvncserver and its already running in my desktop-computer.

How can I create ssh tunnel between my-laptop and company-gw to use vnc-client? Somebody's detailed info would be appreciated. I would like to name my computers as following.

company-pc - desktop computer at work (vnc server)

company-gw - vpn gateway at company (which runs openssh server)

my-laptop  - my laptop computer at home (vnc client)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you cannot connect from company-pc or company-gw to my-laptop, but you can connect from my-laptop to company-gw, and from company-pc to company-gw. Is that right? I don't know what the desktop-computer you refer to is.

If my-laptop is running sshd, try this:

From my-laptop, when you're still at home:

```
ssh -R 8022:localhost:22 myusername@company-gw
```

Once logged in, connections made (from anywhere) to port 8022 on company-gw will be forwarded to port 22 on my-laptop. Stay logged in when you go to work.

At work, from company-pc:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 -p 8022 myhomeusername@company-gw
```

You are actually ssh-ing into my-laptop when you do this, since port 8022 on company-gw is forwarded to port 22 on my-laptop. You are now forwording port 5900 on company-pc to port 5900 on my-laptop (since "localhost" in this command is what my-laptop called localhost).

Now vnc into localhost. That connects to port 5900 on your own company-pc, which is forwarded, via company-gw, to my-laptop.

If any of the forwarded ports is in use, just try a different number (8023 instead of 8022, 5901 instead of the first 5900) until you get to a free one

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround, in case the server has no access or administration rights to enable/start sshd, or when you don't have any user/passwd pair in my-laptop.

On my-laptop, run this:

```
ssh -R 8022:localhost:5900 gw-user@company-gw
```

This way, every use from to company-gw:8022 will be redirected to my-laptop:5900

On company-pc:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:8022 gw-user@company-gw
```

gw-user can be different in the commands; what it matters is that 8022 port is reachable in both ends.